# Lock command discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a lock command but when `fl.lock #general test` is used in #general channel it isn't locking the general channel but when `fl.lock #general test` is used in #staff-chat channel it is locking the #general channel

So my bot isn't locking a channel when that channel is mentioned in the lock commmand and it is used in the same channel

The code

````
  @commands.command(case_insensitive = True)
  @commands.has_any_role(885434191783788564, 856071314740740096, 856061783722426378, 856465667296985108)
  async def lock(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, reason=None): 
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    if overwrite.send_messages == True:
      overwrite.send_messages = False
      await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
      em_reason = discord.Embed(title="**Channel locked**", description=f":lock: {reason}",color=discord.Color.red())
      embed = discord.Embed(description = f"<a:fl_check:874522235879186483> Locked channel <#{channel.id}>",color=discord.Color.green())
      await ctx.send(embed=em_reason)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif overwrite.send_messages == False:
      em = discord.Embed(description="<a:fl_no:874522273984442420> That channel is already locked.", color=discord.Color.red())
      await ctx.send(embed=em)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think `channel = channel or ctx.channel` is the issue here.

You should check directly if the `channel` argument is None and than use the `ctx.channel`.

```
@commands.command(case_insensitive = True)
  @commands.has_any_role(885434191783788564, 856071314740740096, 856061783722426378, 856465667296985108)
  async def lock(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel=None, *, reason=None): 
    if channel is None:
       channel = ctx.channel
    overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    if overwrite.send_messages == True:
      overwrite.send_messages = False
      await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
      em_reason = discord.Embed(title="**Channel locked**", description=f":lock: {reason}",color=discord.Color.red())
      embed = discord.Embed(description = f"<a:fl_check:874522235879186483> Locked channel <#{channel.id}>",color=discord.Color.green())
      await ctx.send(embed=em_reason)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif overwrite.send_messages == False:
      em = discord.Embed(description="<a:fl_no:874522273984442420> That channel is already locked.", color=discord.Color.red())
      await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: Didn't work 
There isn't any error as well in the console